# Toolbar disappeared

Tags: google-docs

I am new to Chromebook and Google Docs. I have started to use and learn both. The toolbar disappeared when I open existing document. The same thing happens when I open a new one.

Comment: Welcome. Please share a screenshot of the issue so you can be easier helped.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can try  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to Hide/Show the menus.